# mdframed - eliminating newline and top/bottom space /margins

Tags: line-breaking, mdframed

I'm totally new to (La)TeX, but trying to learn to become more independent.

So I'm writing a document which includes periodical revisions that need to be marked in a specific way (a thick black vertical line - or a right margin) and decided to use mdframed.

So what I've done so far was defining a "rev"

```
\newmdenv[
  topline=false,
  leftline=false,
  bottomline=false,
  leftmargin=-1em, 
  linewidth=4pt,    
  skipbelow=0
]{rev}
```

and it partly serves my needs, in the sense that with my limited knowledge I was able to remove the extra space (below and to the left) and to add the requested black line to the right side of the element itself.

Now a further improvement would be avoiding the line-break as a whole. Ideally, when a revision to a line or new text begins in the middle of an existing line, the whole line (and all the other lines being part of the mod) should be marked with that vertical line and no line break should happen (besides when the right margin has been hit).

Hope I do make sense.
Thanks everyone, Happy Holidays!

Comment: You can use the following options in your definition: `innerleftmargin=0pt, innerrightmargin=0pt, skipabove=0pt, skipbelow=0pt, innertopmargin=0pt, innerbottommargin=0pt, nobreak=true`. You should also look at [`mdframed`'s manual](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed.pdf), it's well documented.

Comment: Note that `skipabove` and `skipbelow` expect a dimension value (e.g. `10 pt`), not just a number.